# Azure Queue Timing error Win 10 IOT Rpi2

Tags: azure, uwp, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, azure-queues

I am using Azure Storage queues to send notifications to my Rpi2 running win 10 IOT core but I keep getting an error regarding the timing.

I have been able to successfully do this before and it seems to work in only specific timings

Here is the error:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.WrappedStorageException'in mscorlib.ni.dll
Could not get message! Error: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!--An exception has occurred. For more information please deserialize this message via RequestResult.TranslateFromExceptionMessage.-->
<RequestResult>
  <HTTPStatusCode>403</HTTPStatusCode>
  <HttpStatusMessage>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.</HttpStatusMessage>
  <TargetLocation>Primary</TargetLocation>
  <ServiceRequestID>cc716734-0003-0023-67ca-30a635000000</ServiceRequestID>
  <ContentMd5 />
  <Etag />
  <RequestDate>Fri, 28 Oct 2016 02:16:14 GMT</RequestDate>
  <StartTime>Fri, 28 Oct 2016 02:16:13 GMT</StartTime>
  <EndTime>Fri, 28 Oct 2016 02:16:14 GMT</EndTime>
  <Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:cc716734-0003-0023-67ca-30a635000000
Time:2016-10-28T03:21:05.0055931Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Request date header too old: 'Fri, 28 Oct 2016 02:16:14 GMT'</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
  </Error>
  <ExceptionInfo>
    <Type>StorageException</Type>
    <HResult>-2147467259</HResult>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.</Message>
    <Source>Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage</Source>
    <StackTrace>   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.&lt;ExecuteAsyncInternal&gt;d__c`1.MoveNext()</StackTrace>
  </ExceptionInfo>
</RequestResult>
```

My timing on the Rpi seems to be out of sync. but the error output timing seems to be the same, what could be wrong?

Comment: Check if you have problems described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229814/azure-storage-error-using-python-sdk) SO question.

Comment: Yes i have seen that question, but the problem here is that my timings look to already be in sync <RequestDate>Fri, 28 Oct 2016 02:16:14 GMT</RequestDate>
  <StartTime>Fri, 28 Oct 2016 02:16:13 GMT</StartTime>
  <EndTime>Fri, 28 Oct 2016 02:16:14 GMT</EndTime>

Comment: `RequestDate` returned is the server date/time and not the date/time of your computer. Please check if the clock on your computer is correct. Another reason for this error could be incorrect account key. Please check that as well.