# "Request date header too old" error occurred when upload large number of files to blob storage

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have large number of image files on my server (about 900,000), and I'm using Azure Client Library for PHP to make a loop and upload my files to Azure Blob Storage. My upload script ran well for about 2 day, and then suddenly stoped and output below error.

> Oct 19 01:28:14 ik1-315-17878 php: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   exception 'MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Exceptions\ServiceException'
>   with message 'Fail:#012Code: 403#012Value: Server failed to
>   authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
>   is formed correctly including the signature.#012details (if any):
>   `AuthenticationFailed`Server
>   failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the
>   signature.#012RequestId:e7f247d6-001e-0022-142e-48abcc000000#012Time:2017-10-18T16:28:14.4980791ZRequest
>   date header too old: 'Wed, 18 Oct 2017 16:12:27
>   GMT'.' in
>   /home/t-matsumoto/GAZOU/vendor/microsoft/azure-storage/src/Common/Internal/ServiceRestProxy.php:486#012Stack
>   trace:#012#0
>   /home/t-matsumoto/GAZOU/vendor/microsoft/azure-storage/src/Common/Internal/ServiceRestProxy.php(404):
>   MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\ServiceRestProxy::throwIfError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Respon
>   in
>   /home/t-matsumoto/GAZOU/vendor/microsoft/azure-storage/src/Common/Internal/ServiceRestProxy.php
>   on line 486

I've searched about the cause, and it's likely because timestamp when my script made that request was too old comparing to timestamp when Azure received the request. According to the error message above, time of making request is "Wed, 18 Oct 2017 16:12:27 GMT", and time of receiving request is "2017-10-18T16:28:14.4980791Z" (about 15 minutes late). But what I still don't understand is that why my script had run for a while with no error, and then the error occurred suddenly. Can anyone explain to me that phenomenon and solution to make my script run stably with no error.

My php script looks like below

```
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServicesBuilder;
    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;

    $connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=<accountNameHere>;AccountKey=<accountKeyHere>";

    // Create blob REST proxy.
    $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

foreach ($myListFiles as $filename) {
    $content = fopen($filename, "r");
    $blob_name = "myblob";

    //Upload blob
    $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("mycontainer", $blob_name, $content);
}
```

I got uploading sample script from this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Gaurav Mantri has answered your question:

[Azure storage error using Python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229814/azure-storage-error-using-python-sdk)

---

But as you have a large number of image files to upload to Azure storage, I would recommend using [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) to do that. AzCopy is a command-line utility designed for copying data to and from Microsoft Azure Blob, File, and Table storage using simple commands with optimal performance.

Comment: I've read the article you shared but it still doesn't help me to explain my case. Why the error didn't happen at first, and happened when the script was running for a while. Is uploading large number of files the point here which led to time-lag between my server and Azure?